# How to get a context in a recycler view adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, picasso, android-context

I'm trying to use picasso library to be able to load url to imageView, but I'm not able to get the `context` to use the picasso library correctly.

```
public class FeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Post> mDataset;



    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView txtHeader;
        public ImageView pub_image;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstline);
            pub_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        }
    }




    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public FeedAdapter(List<Post> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public FeedAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feedholder, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element

        holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position).getPost_text());

        Picasso.with(this.context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(holder.pub_image);


    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 411, accepted):

You have a few options here:

1. Pass `Context` as an argument to FeedAdapter and keep it as class field
2. Use dependency injection to inject `Context` when you need it.  I strongly suggest reading about it.  There is a great tool for that -- [Dagger](https://github.com/square/Dagger) by Square
3. Get it from any `View` object. In your case this might work for you:

   `holder.pub_image.getContext()`

   As `pub_image` is a `ImageView`.

Comment: I prefer the third option, getting the context from the view. It is the simplest and most straightforward solution.

Comment: or, far better, pass in the Picasso instance, rather than holding a Picasso instance on the class instance and lazy-loading it.

Comment: Each ViewHolder contains an instance of itemView that you pass in the constructor. Use that one like this: itemView.getContext()

Comment: You can't do #2, can you? I tried that, but this will end up being your `ApplicationContext` and not tied to the activity, leading to a runtime crash from within Glide.

Comment: how to pass the component object to the adapter in case I want to use #2?

Comment: In the third option, you can get context from itemView. Like this: 
`holder.itemView.getContext()`

Comment: 3rd one is super simple. 
Just get the package name in the onBindViewHolder or wherever you like, using.
"Context context = viewHolder.mAppIcon.getContext();"
then pass it

Comment: Could 3rd result in a leak?

Answer (score 48):

**Edit**
As [solidak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3870025/solidak) said in [the comments section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136973/how-to-get-a-context-in-a-recycler-view-adapter#comment71900893_34873343), the original answer could lead to memory leak issues, and it's a bad practice to use this method, so it's better to use another method to access the context.

**Original answer:**

You can add a global variable:

```
private Context context;
```

then assign the context from here:

```
@Override
public FeedAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feedholder, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    // set the Context here 
    context = parent.getContext();
    return vh;
}
```

Happy Codding :)

Comment: I strongly suggest AGAINST having global references to Context. This could lead to horrible memory leak issues!!

Comment: if you subclass viewholder, it can be private.

Comment: If the adapter is attached to a RecyclerView then that context is guaranteed to be needed anyway. If you might unattach the adapter, then it's still fine unless for some reason you hold a strong reference to this adapter after it's been detached, in which case you should clear out the cached context, there is a method like `onDetachedFromRecyclerView` or something.

Answer (score 40):

Short answer:

```
Context context;

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    context = recyclerView.getContext();
}
```

Explanation why other answers are not great:

1. Passing `Context` to the adapter is completely unnecessary, since `RecyclerView` you can access it from inside the class
2. Obtaining `Context` at `ViewHolder` level means that you do it every time you bind or create a `ViewHolder`. You duplicate operations.
3. I don't think you need to worry about any memory leak. If your adapter lingers outside your `Activity` lifespan (which would be weird) then you already have a leak.

Comment: In this case, shall we implement `onDetachedFromRecyclerView()` and release context?

Comment: @JohnPang not really unless you want to be extremely defensive. If you keep the adapter reference within the Activity, you are safe.

Comment: And if you **don't** keep a reference to the adapter within the activity? :P

Comment: you're on your own :) today I think I would implement this method as @JohnPang suggested just in case

Answer (score 21):

You can use pub_image context (`holder.pub_image.getContext()`) :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder ViewHolder, int position) {

    holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position).getPost_text());

    Picasso.with(holder.pub_image.getContext()).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(holder.pub_image);


}
```

Answer (score 12):

you can use this:

```
itemView.getContext()
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use like this **view.getContext()**

**Example**

```
holder.tv_room_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

You can define:

```
Context ctx;
```

And on `onCreate` initialise `ctx` to:

```
ctx=parent.getContext();
```

Note: Parent is a ViewGroup.

Answer (score 5):

Create a constructor of FeedAdapter :

```
Context context; //global
public FeedAdapter(Context context)
{
   this.context = context;  
}
```

and in Activity

```
FeedAdapter obj = new FeedAdapter(this);
```

Answer (score 5):

First globally declare

**`Context mContext;`**

pass context with the constructor, by modifying it.

```
public FeedAdapter(List<Post> myDataset, Context context) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
    this.mContext = context;
}
```

then use the `mContext` whereever you need it

Answer (score 4):

```
View mView;
mView.getContext();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25721105)

Answer (score 4):

**SOLUTION:**

When using viewbinding use

```
holder.binding.productImg.context
```

Otherwise use

```
holder.productImg.context
```

Chill Pill :)

Answer (score 2):

First add a global variable

```
Context mContext;
```

Then change your constructor to this

```
public FeedAdapter(Context context, List<Post> myDataset) {
    mContext = context;
    mDataset = myDataset;
}
```

The pass your context when creating the adapter.

```
FeedAdapter myAdapter = new FeedAdapter(this,myDataset);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Databinding on layout you can get the `context` from `holder`. An exemple below.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GenericViewHolder holder, int position) {
    View currentView = holder.binding.getRoot().findViewById(R.id.cycle_count_manage_location_line_layout);// id of your root layout
    currentView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.binding.getRoot().getContext(), R.color.light_green));
}
```