# How to store image from url in Room database (Java)

Tags: android, android-room

I am whoring whole API response to Room database for offline access.
I have managed to store all string values but I want to store image (getting image url in response)into database as well.
Since I have no experience in using Room database, I m confused about how to store image int Room db column
Below is API response

```
{
"beast": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "The Griffin of Edward III",
        "description": "The English Beast has always been a lion",
        "image": "www.google.com/uploads/beast-images/2.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "The Lion of England",
        "description": "The English Beast has always been a lion",
        "image": "www.google.com/uploads/beast-images/2.png"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving Image path from gallery to Room Database and display it in Recycler list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609378/saving-image-path-from-gallery-to-room-database-and-display-it-in-recycler-list)

Comment: @ManthanTilva I m getting image url in response and I want to store it as image in room db

Comment: save the image as blob/ byte array or as  base64 string in room database

Answer (score 0):

You should use BLOB data type to store image. Just annotate image field in Room model class with `@ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)`. Watch this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46356934/5116572) for more information.

Comment: getting com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2104 path $.beastData[0].image error

Comment: @VinodPatil add some code, which causes this exception

Answer (score 0):

You can store the image as a blob type in room DB.
you should convert your image to byte array and save it.
Example:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "image", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
private byte[] image;
```

Comment: getting JsonSyntaxException, Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2104 path $.beastData[0].image