# Using Glide Library with a Fragment adapter

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I have an adapter class that is being used to populate the recyclerview item with cardviews. This RecyclerView is located under a fragment. Inside this adapter, I am trying to bind an image to a imageview which is under the cardview layout. I am trying to achieve that under the following method which is in the adapter class:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Product product = myProducts.get(position);
    holder.productTitle.setText(product.getProductName());
    holder.productDesc.setText(product.getDescription());
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(product.getImageUri());
    Glide.with(/*WHAT SHOULD I PASS HERE??*/).load(new File(uri.getPath())).into(holder.productImage);
}
```

Each product instance has a field which contains path to an image and I want to take that path, find corresponding image and draw it in the cardview item. But I have no idea what should I pass to `Glide.with()` as an argument. Thanks in advance and please point out anything seems wrong. I am very novice in android programming.

Edit: Following is the holder class.

```
class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView productImage;
    private TextView productTitle;
    private TextView productDesc;

    public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        productImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
        productTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_title);
        productDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_desc);
    }

}
```

And I have tried this

```
Glide.with(holder.itemView).load(new File(uri.getPath())).into(holder.productImage);
```

But it gave an error like this:

```
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There were 3 causes:
java.io.IOException(File unsuitable for memory mapping)
java.io.FileNotFoundException(/document/msf:24: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
```

This is my adapter class:

```
 public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    private final LayoutInflater myInflater;
    private List<Product> myProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    public ProductAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view_product, parent, false);
        return new ProductViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Product product = myProducts.get(position);
        holder.productTitle.setText(product.getProductName());
        holder.productDesc.setText(product.getDescription());
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(product.getImageUri());
        Glide.with(context).load(new File(uri.getPath())).into(holder.productImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myProducts.size();
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        myProducts = products;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView productImage;
        private TextView productTitle;
        private TextView productDesc;

        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            productImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
            productTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_title);
            productDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_desc);
        }

    }
}
```

And the error

```
    W/Glide: Load failed for /document/msf:25 with size [384x384]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There were 3 causes:
    java.io.IOException(File unsuitable for memory mapping)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/document/msf:25: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.nio.ByteBuffer, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.IOException(File unsuitable for memory mapping)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.IOException: File unsuitable for memory mapping
      Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/document/msf:25: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/msf:25: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
      Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 3)
    java.io.IOException: File unsuitable for memory mapping
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.ByteBufferUtil.fromFile(ByteBufferUtil.java:38)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ByteBufferFileLoader$ByteBufferFetcher.loadData(ByteBufferFileLoader.java:61)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
I/Glide: Root cause (2 of 3)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/msf:25: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$StreamFactory$1.open(FileLoader.java:142)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$StreamFactory$1.open(FileLoader.java:139)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:71)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:408)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailedInternal(SourceGenerator.java:160)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator$1.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:83)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ByteBufferFileLoader$ByteBufferFetcher.loadData(ByteBufferFileLoader.java:66)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7255)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$StreamFactory$1.open(FileLoader.java:142) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$StreamFactory$1.open(FileLoader.java:139) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:71) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:408) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailedInternal(SourceGenerator.java:160) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator$1.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:83) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ByteBufferFileLoader$ByteBufferFetcher.loadData(ByteBufferFileLoader.java:66) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393) 
I/Glide: Root cause (3 of 3)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:315)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:220)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileDescriptorFactory$1.open(FileLoader.java:166)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileDescriptorFactory$1.open(FileLoader.java:163)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:71)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:408)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailedInternal(SourceGenerator.java:160)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator$1.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:83)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:76)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:408)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailedInternal(SourceGenerator.java:160)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator$1.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:83)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ByteBufferFileLoader$ByteBufferFetcher.loadData(ByteBufferFileLoader.java:66)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
```

I debug the code to see does the path of an image returns successfully and it does. But it is not showing up in the list item. I think there is nothing wrong in the part where addition process happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to pass the context of your activity/fragment which contains the image view in the `with()`.

you can achieve this by passing the context of your activity in your adapter constructor.
for example, your Adapter constructor might look like that:

```
myAdapter(Context context, List<Object> dataset) {
            this.context = context;
            ...
            ...
               }
```

and when you create an instance from the adapter you can pass the context like this:

```
myAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this,...);
```

then you can use the context for Glide like this:

```
Glide.with(context)
```

I hope this helps, if you need more clarifications, let me know in the comments!

Comment: I have added the my all adapter class and the error. Could you please check the adapter class? Thank you and sorry for bothering.

Comment: can you debug and copy the url and paste it in your browser. do you see the image?

Comment: I just realized that it gives me `Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:25 flg=0x1 }` as a reply which is uri. But when I convert it to string it becomes `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A25`. However, I have already parse it back to Uri under the adapter.

Comment: But pasting uri to browser gives me nothing. Says your file not found. I have pasted this: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:25

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332003/glide-load-local-image-by-uri check this. I think this is the same issue you are facing now

Comment: Changing the `new File(uri.getPath())` to just `uri.getPath()` does not give any error now. But image itself still does not show up.

Comment: did you add this permission to your manifest  ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />``` ?

Comment: Yes, its there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212729/discussion-between-remon-shehatta-and-zodiac645).

Comment: Please note that in addition to answer, the line `Glide.with(context).load(new File(uri.getPath())).into(holder.productImage);` replaces with `Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse(product.getImageUri)).into(holder.productImage);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want use glide in fragment adapter use can use the below code:
`Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(arrayList[position].image) .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(RoundedCorners(20))) .into(viewImage)`