# I can't open fragment in Recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have problem with opening fragment from recyclerview item. When I click button inside item I get the message with error: onEditClick(com.example.taskapprealm.edit.EditFragment)' on a null object reference. Null is inside the Adapter.

Method inside MainActivity:

```
 @Override
public void onEditClick(EditFragment editFragment) {
    Fragment fragment = new EditFragment();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.recycler_view, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

and onBindViewHolder in Adapter:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TaskViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
   Task task = tasks.get(position);
   holder.textItem.setText(task.getText());
   holder.dateItem.setText(task.getDate());
   holder.timeItem.setText(task.getTime());
   holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
           Log.d(TAG, "DELETE_CLICK " + holder.getAdapterPosition());
           callback.onDeleteClick(position);
           notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
       }

   });


   holder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "TEST " + holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           mainActivity.onEditClick(editFragment);
       }
   });

}
```

Interface:

```
 void onEditClick(EditFragment editFragment);
```

Logs:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.taskapprealm.debug, PID: 8045
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.taskapprealm.main.MainActivity.onEditClick(com.example.taskapprealm.edit.EditFragment)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.taskapprealm.main.MainAdapter$2.onClick(MainAdapter.java:94)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: can you post your crash logs?

Comment: Yes. I just pasted.

Comment: Your `mainActivity` is null inside your `Adapter`

Comment: I know it. How to call MainActivity?

Comment: Ok I just changed recyclerview_item on main_activity in method in MainActivity and I also changed this code in Adapter: mainActivity.onEditClick(editFragment);
on this:
 callback.onEditClick(position);

Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Would you please explain what `mainActivity` is and where you initialize `editFragment` in this line ` mainActivity.onEditClick(editFragment);`

Comment: Also would you please add full adapter class with your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to open a different fragment on recyclerview OnClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984879/how-to-open-a-different-fragment-on-recyclerview-onclick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are referencing `RecyclerView` instead of your `Fragment` container in:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.recycler_view, fragment);
```

---

Probably, `recycler_view` should be replaced with your `Fragment` container. Also, check if `EditFragment` view is correct and not replaced by any mistakes or typo in `onCreateView()` method.

Also, as mentioned, `mainActivity` looks null.

**Read:** [How to get a context in a recycler view adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136973/how-to-get-a-context-in-a-recycler-view-adapter)

Comment: Yep. You had right. It was my first time with fragment and recyclerview and I didn't now that.