# getContext() not recognised

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-context

In `getContext()` its showing "Non-static method 'getContext()' cannot be referenced from a static context" how to solve it,or what should i call instead of it.

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder > {

private List<CategoryModel> CategoryModelList;

public CategoryAdapter(List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList) {
    CategoryModelList = categoryModelList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(ViewGroup.getContext()).Inflate(R.layout.category_item,viewGroup,false);
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ViewGroup is the class

Comment: I don't think closing questions like this as duplicates of a canonical "what is Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" and how do I fix it. Therefore, reopened.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136973/how-to-get-a-context-in-a-recycler-view-adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `ViewGroup` but it should be `viewGroup`

Comment: checked as answer so it can help others

Answer (score 4):

```
ViewGroup.getContext()
```

try with:

```
viewGroup.getContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder > {
private Context context;

private List<CategoryModel> CategoryModelList;

public CategoryAdapter(List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList, Context Mcontext) {
    CategoryModelList = categoryModelList;
    this.context = Mcontext;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).Inflate(R.layout.category_item,viewGroup,false);
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```